# How to add a cross-out "/" to any latex symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I want to type something like this

[image]

How to add a `/` in a latex symbol in general? Like the `\nexists`, `\notin`.

Comment: Is `\bcancel` okay?

Comment: Your write-up is a bit confusing: the screenshot shows a backward-leaning slash character, but `\notin` and `\nexists` (requires the `amssymb` package) use a forward-leaning slash. Which type of slash character do wish to employ?

Comment: @Mico Sorry my sense of direction is so not good that both slashes look same to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many possible ways, here are three of them:

1. a simple `\not`,
2. `\cancel`,
3. or a Ti*k*Zy `strike out`.

Some people would call Ti*k*Z overkill, others just very flexible, in the end it is up to you to decide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
$\in$ $\not\in$ $\cancel\in$ $\tikzmarknode[strike out,draw]{1}{\in}$

$B$ $\not B$ $\cancel{B}$ $\tikzmarknode[strike out,draw]{2}{B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `\not` works only well for selected symbols. `\cancel` is arguably nicer but also not too easy to customize. Personally I would say that loading Ti*k*Z only for that might be too much, but if you are thinking of using it anyway, this might be a more flexible alternative to the more traditional approaches.